# Excel Power Query: Merge tables where one needs to be grouped first

Tags: excel, merge, powerquery

I'm an experienced SQL programmer but as access to db is getting cut in our company, I am more and more obliged to work with Power Query, which feels quite humiliating to be honest.

I haven't seen yet how to merge 2 tables, if the second table needs to be grouped first. The corresponding operation in SQL would be

```
select a.ID, b.value
from tableA a
   left outer join (select ID, SUM(value) as value
                    from tableB
                    group by ID)b on a.ID = b.ID
```

is there a way to do this within one query or would I need to create a separate query first where I'm preparing the table and then refer in the merge operation to that query?
This is just an easy example where one could do the grouping after the join. I'm not interested in that solution.

---

This is what I want to achieve:
I have one Data Connection (query1) to an SQL Server with all customers and 2 Data Connections to 2 different Excels (query2 & query3), exported from the ERP. I need to merge the customer Table with each of the other queries that priorly should be aplied a where clause to and grouped by customer.

Comment: You can do this easily writing `M Code` in the `Advanced Editor`. If you are working solely in the UI, you would need to group them within two separate queries, and then join them.

Answer (score 2):

Load both tables (TableA and TableB) into Power Query.

Group TableA by a specific column (let's assume it's "ColumnA") and calculate the desired aggregation (e.g., sum, count, etc.). Let's call this step "GroupedTableA".

Group TableB by the "ID" column and calculate the desired aggregation for the "value" column (e.g., sum, count, etc.). Name this step "GroupedTableB".

Then Merge GroupedTableA and GroupedTableB using the common column(s) between them.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for the quick response, but this isn't what my question aimed at. So if TableA also would need some grouping operation first too, then I probably need some other solution. Can I do this within one Query or would I need to prepare this in a separate query?

Comment: Your answer makes me understand that one can load in the same query different tables/queries but I can't see how. I thought that a step in a query was an operation on the previous. I specified the whole operation in my question.

Comment: as I understand it you cannot directly merge two tables in Power Query where the second table requires grouping without using intermediate steps or separate queries.  you would need to perform the grouping operation on TableB in a separate step or query, and then reference that grouped table in the merge operation.